# Using data structure classes (node list) with another class

Tags: c++, class, data-structures

Im trying to put information from another class into a nodal based list class. For example i have a class card, and then i want to put those cards which are in an array, into my nodal based list class. IM just trying to get my head around the syntax. Do I need to make my card class a friend of the node and list class.

Ill have a total of 2 classes (node and list) that will contain information from the card class. I know i have to template the node and list, im confused just how and why?

```
 ./class.h:5:7: error: redefinition of 'card'
class card {
      ^
./class.h:5:7: note: previous definition is here
class card {
      ^
In file included from project8.cpp:9:
In file included from ./nodallist.cpp:2:
In file included from ./listN.h:4:
In file included from ./class.cpp:3:
./class.h:35:7: error: redefinition of 'player'
class player{
      ^
./class.h:35:7: note: previous definition is here
class player{
      ^
In file included from project8.cpp:9:
./nodallist.cpp:7:7: error: out-of-line definition of 'Node' does not match any
      declaration in 'Node'
Node::Node(card value, Node* nodeyo)
      ^~~~
./nodallist.cpp:9:5: error: assigning to 'char' from incompatible type 'card'
data=value;
    ^~~~~~
./nodallist.cpp:149:12: error: out-of-line definition of 'insertAfter' does not
      match any declaration in 'List'
bool List::insertAfter(card value)
           ^~~~~~~~~~~
./nodallist.cpp:153:18: error: no matching constructor for initialization of
      'Node'
        Node *newd= new Node(value,NULL);
                        ^    ~~~~~~~~~~
./listN.h:12:3: note: candidate constructor not viable: no known conversion from
      'card' to 'char' for 1st argument
                Node(char, Node*);
                ^
./listN.h:10:7: note: candidate constructor (the implicit copy constructor) not
      viable: requires 1 argument, but 2 were provided
class Node{
      ^
In file included from project8.cpp:9:
./nodallist.cpp:160:19: error: no matching constructor for initialization of
      'Node'
        Node *noden= new Node(value,cursor->next);
                         ^    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
./listN.h:12:3: note: candidate constructor not viable: no known conversion from
      'card' to 'char' for 1st argument
                Node(char, Node*);
                ^
./listN.h:10:7: note: candidate constructor (the implicit copy constructor) not
      viable: requires 1 argument, but 2 were provided
class Node{
      ^
In file included from project8.cpp:9:
./nodallist.cpp:167:12: error: out-of-line definition of 'insertBefore' does not
      match any declaration in 'List'
bool List::insertBefore(card value)
           ^~~~~~~~~~~~
./nodallist.cpp:171:19: error: no matching constructor for initialization of
      'Node'
                Node *newd= new Node(value,NULL);
                                ^    ~~~~~~~~~~
./listN.h:12:3: note: candidate constructor not viable: no known conversion from
      'card' to 'char' for 1st argument
                Node(char, Node*);
                ^
./listN.h:10:7: note: candidate constructor (the implicit copy constructor) not
      viable: requires 1 argument, but 2 were provided
class Node{
      ^
In file included from project8.cpp:9:
./nodallist.cpp:180:14: error: assigning to 'char' from incompatible type 'card'
        cursor->data=value;
                    ^~~~~~
./nodallist.cpp:185:12: error: out-of-line definition of 'remove' does not match
      any declaration in 'List'
bool List::remove(card &value)
           ^~~~~~
./nodallist.cpp:225:12: error: out-of-line definition of 'replace' does not
      match any declaration in 'List'
bool List::replace(card value)
           ^~~~~~~
./nodallist.cpp:233:13: error: assigning to 'char' from incompatible type 'card'
cursor->data=value;
            ^~~~~~
./nodallist.cpp:238:12: error: out-of-line definition of 'getCursor' does not
      match any declaration in 'List'
bool List::getCursor(card &value) const
           ^~~~~~~~~
project8.cpp:19:12: error: redefinition of 'SPACE'
const char SPACE = ' ';
           ^
./class.cpp:9:12: note: previous definition is here
const char SPACE= ' ';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class card
{
    /* stuff */
};

class node
{
    /* other stuff */;
    card c;
};
```

If you want to have data for a card in a node, just put the card in the node.

Comment: I did that and in my main tried to call it by creating a list first then putting a card into the list. I got a fat error. Heres some of the errors

Comment: Did you #include the file with 'card' in the file with 'node' and also in the .cpp file? If you did, that's why - because then it reads the definition of "card" twice. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard for the usual way to work around this. (include guards will make the compiler ignore the file the second time, if it's included twice)

Comment: thanks, i used a makefile to make things easier. Then i forward declarated the class card now i get variable has incomplete type?

Comment: To use "card c;" you have to declare the "card" class first - a forward declaration won't do. Have you tried the other way around?

Answer (score 0):

It's quite easy... In class card, take two functions- one for entering information for each card(Use the concept of arrays of objects for that). After that, try to implement what is known as "Queue Using Linked List". And yes, using the template class: Queue in C++ you can implement it very easily,but you may try this approach as well! Good luck! :)

Comment: do you mean a constructor? And my node and list classes are friends and creates a linked list with nodes.